# How to retrieve value from widgets put in a fixed container Gtk

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

Whenever i retrieve values from combobox / entry i always get the first value / returns null.

I can't seem to find a workaround. I think the problem seems to lie in using a fixed container? The only solution i can think of is to replace it with a grid layout but that means i will have to redo my entire code from the start.

**creating the fixed container**

```
class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self): #constructor
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="dawadaw")
        self.set_size_request(900, 700)
        container = Gtk.Fixed()
        self.add(container)

                # Stack
        main_area = Gtk.Stack()

                #stackwindow1
        sw1 = Gtk.Fixed()
```

**Combobox and entry**

```
        list = Gtk.ComboBoxText()
            list.append_text("string1")
            list.append_text("string2")
            list.append_text("string3")
            list.set_active(0)
            sw1.put(list, 180, 167)

        Entry1 = Gtk.Entry()
        Entry1.set_width_chars(10)
        sw1.put(Entry1, 180, 297)
```

**button to retrieve data**

```
        button = Gtk.Button(label="retrieve values")
        button.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked, 
        Entry1.get_text(), sw1.get_active_text())
        sw1.put(button, 370, 600)

        main_area.add_titled(sw1, "Stack", "stack1")
```

**Button_Clicked funtcion**

```
def button_clicked(self, button, *data):
    print(data)
```

I want to print the selected combobox value and the value i entered in the entry box. However, the combobox only returns the string1, regardless of what i select and the entry widget does not return anything.

I'm stuck and i think the problem lies with me using a fixed container. But i don't want to redo everything if i don't have to.
Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your example will not work, you didn't add `sw1`. Fixed this leads to `AttributeError: 'Fixed' object has no attribute 'get_active_text'`. Fixed this i can reproduce your behavior. Your error is: `.connect("clicked",..., Entry1.get_text(), list.get_active_text())`. Here you assign **static** init values as parameter to the `callback` wich ist: empty `''` for `Entry1` and `'string1'` for list. **Solution**: Move `Entry1.get_text(), list.get_active_text())` to `def button_clicked(...`.

Comment: i didnt add sw1 in my example because i forgot to. In my actual program there are no errors. Ill re-edit the example. When i put Entry1.get_text() and list.get_active_text() to def button_clicked() i get attribute not defined, even with self infront

Comment: ***"get attribute not defined"***: You have to make it a `class member`, change to `self.Entry1 = Entry1 = Gtk.Entry()`. Do also for `self.list`. Read [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: its solved now, thanks so much!!!